# Are these the isolated singularities?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity, singularity-theory

Find the isolated singularities of the function $$f(z)=\frac{e^z-1}{z^4(z^2+4\pi^2)}$$
$$$$

I have done the following :

We set the denominator equal to zero : $$z^4(z^2+4\pi^2)=0 \Rightarrow z=0 \text{ or } z^2+4\pi^2=0 \Rightarrow z=\pm 2\pi i$$ These are the isolated singularities, right?

Comment: Yes that's right. Examples of non isolated singularities would be curves, such as in$$\frac{1}{|z|^2-1}$$ or accumulations points, such as $z=0$ in $$\frac{1}{\sin \frac{1}{z}}$$

Comment: To check the isolated singularities do we not have to check if the zeroes of the denominator are also zeroes of the numerator? @NinadMunshi

Comment: isolated singularities can also be removable singularities! But if you are making sure that what you have are nontrivial poles then yes you are absolutely right

Comment: $z=0$ is also a zero of the numerator. What does this mean then? @NinadMunshi

Comment: $z=\pm 2\pi i$ are also zeros of the numerator. What do you think this means?

Comment: Now we have to check the order of numerator and denominator to check if the zeroes are removable or not? @NinadMunshi

Comment: Exactly! You have the right approach. What do you think the order of the zeros are in the numerator, and how do they compare to the order of the zeros in the denominator?

Comment: We have $$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{z^4(e^z-1)}{z^4(z^2+4\pi^2)}=0 \\ \lim_{z\rightarrow 2\pi i}\frac{(z^2+4\pi^2)(e^z-1)}{z^4(z^2+4\pi^2)}=0  \\ \lim_{z\rightarrow -2\pi i}\frac{(z^2+4\pi^2)(e^z-1)}{z^4(z^2+4\pi^2)}=0 $$ 
Is that correct? So all singularities are removable. Is that correct? @NinadMunshi

Comment: Not quite, because you multiplied by too many powers in the numerator. Generally that technique of multiplying by some power and then taking a limit to the pole to find the residue only works *if you know the order of the pole in advance*, so I suggest using an alternate method - follow the outline from earlier and consider the numerator and denominator separately first. What is the order (aka power) of the zeros in each? As your first hint the order of zero at $z=0$ in the denominator is $4$.

Comment: In the denominator $z=0$ is of order $4$, $z=\pm 2\pi i$ is of order $2$, right? For the numerator do we check the derivatives to get the order of the zeroes? @NinadMunshi

Comment: Why osn't $z=0$ a zero of the denominator? @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: @MaryStar Actually I meant not a zero of the numerator. Which is of course nonsense...

Comment: The order of the denominator zeros are 4,1, and 1, respectively. An order 2 zero at $z=z_0$ would look like $(z-z_0)^2$, not $z^2-z_0^2 = (z-z_0)(z+z_0)$

Comment: Ahh ok! I see! Thank you!! :-)